# Automatically change data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out on how to change a column values automatically when I assign a value to a specific column. Details as follows;

```
     Body                     ADE              HDU            Double
Hello John                     0                0                0
你好                           5                0                0
Cassidy! Hi                    0                0                0
வணக்கம் அங்கே                 5             AA123455            0
```

As you can see above, this is part of my csv files, which contains thousands of rows. Column 'ADE' consist of 0 and 5 where 0 is normal alphabet and 5 indicates UNICODE character. 'HDU' column represent the 'Body' column that consist more than 153 character in 'Body' column.

The goals here, when I open my csv file, if I put 'Ft0' in front of the text in the 'Body' column , it will update the value in 'Double' to '1'. 
For example:

```
Body                      ADE         HDU             Double
Ft0 Hello John             0           0                1
```

Below is my current codes;

```
for p5 in df:
            if df = df[(df['ADE'] == '0') & (df['HDU'].isnull())]:
               if df.loc[df['Body'].str.len(156)]
```

[image]

[image]

This is where I get stuck with my codes. I've tried with np.where, if conditions.
I am quite new to pandas and a week grasp with python.

I would appreciate your suggestion to achieve my desire output.

Appreciate and thank you very much!

Comment: your question is unclear and there are typos, but I helped you out with one of your lines of code: **df.loc[(df['ADE'] == 0) & (df['HDU'].isnull())]**

Comment: Hi @DavidErickson, appreciate your highlighting on my post, have corrected it. I want to change a value of a 'Double' column when I add 'Ft0' in front of the text. When I made a changes in the csv file. Is that possible? Like in excel we can set a formula in the cell, however, I'm trying to implement this on pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.

```
df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('Ft0'), 'Double'] = 1
```

Update

Original dataframe

```
             Body  ADE  HDU  Double
0  Ft0 Hello John    0    0       0
```

Applied code:

```
df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('Ft0'), 'Double'] = 1
```

Result:

```
             Body  ADE  HDU  Double
0  Ft0 Hello John    0    0       1
```

Comment: Hi @talatccan doesn't work, I've tried with .str.startswith also doesn't work.

Comment: Original data frame does not consist 'Ft0'

Comment: You should run the code after put `Ft0`. How do you put 'Ft0'?

Comment: Your current code in the question is the way how you are putting Ft0?

Comment: The changes made when I do on my .csv file once I open it. I run the code and open again, it didn't change the value.

Comment: If you are sure that you changed the value (added Ft0) in Body column it should work. The problem should be something else. Are you sure you saved the file after your changes?

Comment: Yup, 100 percent I did save my file. But thanks for helping out, never cross my mind that something else would cause an error, will try to dig on to this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see Ft0 in the excel screenshot anywhere. Also, are you reading in the file with df= pd.read_csv('filename.csv'). You must be fundamentally not undersanding something basic here. It should work with df.loc[df['Body'].str.contains('Ft0'), 'Double'] = 1 OR df['Double'] = np.where(df['Body'].str.contains('Ft0'), 1, df['Double']). What is the error you are receiving? Your errors might have nothing to do with that. It could be that you have lots of international characters and unicode format.

Answer (score 1):

@Syafiq Rosli try

```
df['Double'] = np.where(df['Body'].str.contains('Ft0'), 1, df['Double'])
```

Comment: I've tried this before, but when I open my csv file and add "Ft0' in "Body' column, it didn't change the value.

Comment: @Syafiq Rosli save the .csv file, close it and run the python script again. Then, it should work.

Comment: no dice. I've tried it, and also did with '.str.startswith' still doesn't work as well

Comment: @Syafiq Rosli can you take a screenshot of your excel data and your python code and post it?

Comment: As requested for your reference